# Json Web Token - Como criar um token que acesse apenas determinada Controller ou Action?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Estou implementando o JWT numa aplicação .Net Core 2.0 e gostaria de saber como restringir o acesso de tokens a determinadas Controllers.

Answer (score 2):

O que você quer fazer pode ser feito com `Roles` e `Claims`.

Por exemplo, durante a autenticação voce poderá adicionar uma `Role` no token "Compras" ou "Vendas".

No token: `"roles":  ["Compras", "Vendas"]` //Adicione as roles que o usuário possuir acesso.

Nas `controller` de compras:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Compras")]
public class ComprasController : Controller
```

Na `controller` de vendas:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Vendas")]
public class VendasController : Controller
```

Dessa forma, as duas controllers precisaram estar autenticados, mas somente será acessado se o usuário autenticado possuir a `Role` especifica.

Segue uma referência desta implementação: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-roles-with-the-jwt-middleware/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Blz, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Para restringir um `Controller` com um JWT, ou seja, obrigar o acesso ao mesmo somente com um `Token`, coloque o atributo `Authorize` em cima do `Controller` desejado:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AuthController : Controller
{ }
```

Dessa forma, todos os métodos desse `Controller` precisarão de um `Token` para serem acessados.

Caso queira definir algum método que não precise de um `Token`, coloque o atributo `AllowAnonymous` em cima do método desejado:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("Token")]
public IActionResult CreateToken([FromBody]Login login)
{ }
```

Para um tutorial completo e funcional de como criar uma aplicação ASP.NET Core com JWT, pode seguir esse tutorial: [Securing ASP.NET Core 2.0 Applications with JWTs](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/)

Comment: Na verdade o que eu queria era mais ou menos assim, eu tenho duas Controllers, eu quero que um token gerado tenha acesso a uma mas não a outra. Sendo que as duas precisariam de um token para ser acessadas. Quero dizer a quais Controllers específicas aquele token pode acessar.

Comment: Ou seja, exatamente o que eu escrevi acima. Quer que um Controller precise de Token, coloca o Authorize. Não quer que o Controller precise de Token, não coloca.

Comment: Não. Quero que todas precisem de Authorize. Mas que o token só tenha acesso a Authorizes específicos. Digamos que eu tenha um API para atender a área de vendas e de compras. As duas áreas precisam ter seus métodos protegidos, mas o token da área de vendas não pode acessar  a de compras e vice e versa.

Comment: Para isso, você pode fazer o uso de Claims, que nada mais são do que alguns dados que tu pode passar junto com o Token para fazer a validação depois na hora de chegar na sua API. Nesse caso, você usaria o mesmo token, mas passando a área desejada junto com o Token. Na hora que a requisição chega na API, tu verifica se tal área pode acessar o recurso ou não. No link que coloquei na resposta explica também como fazer o uso de Claims.

Comment: Blz, obrigado pela ajuda